# setdefault - add more than one value to the key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am working on a script where I need to scan a list as in the format below

```
[jobname,username,permissions]
```

After which i need to setup a dictionary which would provide information in the format below

```
jobname -> [username ] - [perm1,perm2]
```

Here perms could be permissions like read/write etc.So for a single job, multiple users can be present and can have have different permissions.

At present I am using setdefault as below:

```
   def mapData(self):
       """
       Create a dictionary from the list of jobs information 
       gathered in parser
       """
       self.fDict={}
       for jobName,uname,perms in self.TestArray:
           #print jobName
           #Need a way to add multiple perms 
           #The program for now only adds the last perm value as expected
           self.fDict.setdefault(jobName,{})[uname]=perms

           '''
           DEBUG
           '''
           #for k,v in self.fDict.items():
               #print 'Key->>'+str(k)+'->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+str(v)
```

As mentioned in the comment, I am able to add only the last perm value which is not what is needed. I need something like list.append(perms) for the value section as well but unable to figure this out. Guidance please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have *2 levels* here; a dictionary containing dictionaries containing lists. Add another `setdefault()` call:

```
self.fDict.setdefault(jobName, {}).setdefault(uname, []).append(perms)
```

Now `fDict` contains dictionaries keyed on `jobName`, where those contained dictionaries contain lists of `perm` values, keyed on `uname`.

Demo:

```
>>> test_list = [['foo_job', 'bar_user', 'baz_permission'], ['foo_job', 'bar_user', 'spam_permission']]
>>> fDict = {}
>>> for jobName, uname, perms in test_list:
...     fDict.setdefault(jobName, {}).setdefault(uname, []).append(perms)
... 
>>> fDict
{'foo_job': {'bar_user': ['baz_permission', 'spam_permission']}}
```